# Script to apply Simple Finder restrictions to Mac OS X user?

Tags: mac-osx, bash, scripting, user-management

Is it possible to script (e.g. with AppleScript or bash shell script) applying the Simple Finder and an associated application whitelist to a local user account on Mac OS X? We are using Mac OS X 10.8.5 and have a need to be able to do this on multiple Macs. As it is not a network account we cannot use Workgroup Manager for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Profiles.

You can make a profile through Server.app's web interface. You can download Apple's Server.app from the App Store.

Then you can script the install:
`sudo profiles -I -F /path/to/profile.mobileconfig`

Example Finder Payload:

[image: Finder profile payload]

Example Restrictions Payload:

[image: Restrictions Payload]

[More Info Here](http://training.apple.com.au/pdf/wp_osx_configuration_profiles_ml.pdf)